# How do multi-indices work, step by step?

Tags: summation, index-notation

Never used multi-indexed summations in my life, neither has anyone else I know.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

does not define an upper index for the multi-indexed sum, which gives the sum no meaning whatsoever.

However, it does for some reason have an ordered set of numbers as an index for a multi-indexed sum and then completely fails to explain the procedure for each of those indices in that set. Is it a nested sum? A product of sums? A sum of products? Is each sum a coefficient of some polynomial? Is each polynomial a coefficient of some sum? And to what end-index? How do you use any part of this theorem? The world may never know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91442/discussion-on-question-by-vane-voe-how-do-multi-indices-work-step-by-step).

Answer (score 1):

Here we look at the connection between binomial expansion and multinomial expansion for the cases $n=2$  and     $n=3$ which might  give a better idea what's going on.

> **Case $n=2$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(x_1+x_2)^n}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\binom{n}{k_1}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{n-k_1}}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\frac{n!}{k_1!(n-k_1)!}x_1^{x_1}x_2^{n-k_1}\\
> &=\sum_{{k_1+k_2=n}\atop{k_1,k_2\geq   0}}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{{k_1+k_2=n}\atop{k_1,k_2\geq   0}}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In  (1)  we   introduce  a  new index variable  $k_2=n-k_1$. Note we also state in the index  region $k_1,k_2\geq 0$  which  is sometimes  silently assumed.

> **Case   $n=3$:**
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(x_1+x_2+x_3)^n}&=(x_1+(x_2+x_3))^n\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\binom{n}{k_1}x_1^{k_1}(x_2+x_3)^{n-k_1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\binom{n}{k_1}x_1^{k_1}\sum_{k_2=0}^{n-k_1}\binom{n-k_1}{k_2}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{n-k_1-k_2}}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\sum_{k_2=0}^{n-k_1}\frac{n!}{k_1!(n-k_1)!}\cdot\frac{(n-k_1)!}{k_2!(n-k_1-k_2)!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{n-k_1-k_2}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\sum_{k_2=0}^{n-k_1}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!(n-k_1-k_2)!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{n-k_1-k_2}\\
> &=\sum_{k_1=0}^n\sum_{{k_2+k_3=n-k_1}\atop{k_2,k_3\geq 0}}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{k_3}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!k_3!}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{k_3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{{k_1+k_2+k_3=n}\atop{k_1,k_2,k_3\geq 0}}\binom{n}{k_1,k_2,k_3}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}x_3^{k_3}}\\
> \end{align*}

- In  (2)  we   introduce  a  new index variable  $k_3=n-k_1-k_2$  similarly as  we did in  (1).

*Hint:* You might find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.

Comment: How do you "ensure" $k_1$ and $k_2$ always add up to $n$? They could be any random integer. It looks like there are $|K|-1$ nested sums. Frankly I would prefer nested sums to over-specified notation. Would the next nested sum for 4 terms to the power of $n$ be from $k_3$ to $k_1-k_2$ or to $n-k_1-k_2$?

Comment: @VaneVoe: The expression $k_1+k_2=n$ *ensures* that $k_1$ and $k_2$ always add up to $n$. Since we also have   $k_1,k_2\geq 0$ we always have valid tupel $(k_1,k_2)=(k_1,n-k_1)$ as in the line above.

Comment: That expressing gives no information on what $k_1$ and $k_2$ actually are. Is $k_1$ 1? Is it 2? Is it $n-1$? Is it $n-2$? Is it $3!$?

Comment: But is the nested sum principal right? That would make it easier to understand.

Comment: @VaneVoe: There is no difference at all. Recall we have an equality chain. It's just a matter of convenience which kind of representation we choose. In my answer an interesting aspect could be to go from the more familiar binomial representation step by step to the multinomial representation and try to grasp *why* these representations all mean the same.

Comment: Okay, so I think what you are trying to say is "yes". Assuming that is true, is the next nested sum from $k_{i+1}$ to $k_i-k_{i+1}$ or is the next nested sum from $k_{i+1}$ to {n-k_{1}-k_{2}...k_{i}$?

Comment: @VaneVoe: Correct, it's "yes". Consider $(x_1+x_2+(x_3+x_4))^n$, the crucial step from $n=3$ to $n=4$ is in the blue marked line: $x_3^{n-k_1-k_2}\to(x_3+x_4)^{n-k_1-k_2}=\sum_{k_3=0}^{n-k_1-k_2}\binom{n-k_1-k_2}{k_3}x_3^{k_3}x_4^{\color{blue}{n-k_1-k_2-k_3}}$. Now you should be able to answer your question by yourself. :-)

Comment: I think some of what you said was a bit misleading. When you gave an $f(s)$ example and I tried to confirm it, you said it was right even though it was wrong. You can't merely take the function within sum and apply it to each element in the set, you need the entire sum itself too, and the upper boundaries aren't vague, they range from 1 to the $m$th element being raised to the nth power, that's the only way to explain the nested sums. The trinomial theorem in its explicit double sum form does not match what you presented either.